# Rails 5 Postgres: Is there a DB constraint for inclusion?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I'm trying to ensure (as far as possible) that I have equivalent database constraints for each of my model validations. A lot of my models have a `status` column and I'm using the `inclusion:` validation to ensure the status value is in my whitelisted array.

```
validates :status, inclusion: { in: %w[pending active inactive] }
```

Is there an equivalent constraint for the DB that I can add to the `create_table` migration?

(Using Rails 5.2.4.1 with Postgres)

Answer (score 3):

Postgres has a [native enum type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/datatype-enum.html) which is actually better than a constraint in a lot of ways.

> Enumerated (enum) types are data types that comprise a static, ordered
>   set of values. They are equivalent to the enum types supported in a
>   number of programming languages. An example of an enum type might be
>   the days of the week, or a set of status values for a piece of data.

This addresses one the popular criticisms of ActiveRecord::Enum integer columns which that you can't tell just from looking the database what the statuses actually mean. Its also not like just using a string column since the values are mapped to a lookup table and only occupy 4 bites on disk each.

```
class AddStatusToProjects < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def up
    execute <<-SQL
      CREATE TYPE project_status AS ENUM ('pending', 'active', 'inactive');
    SQL
    add_column :project, :status, :project_status
  end

  def down
    remove_column :projects, :status
    execute <<-SQL
      DROP TYPE project_status;
    SQL
  end
end
```

Then setup an explicit mapping for the Enum in your model:

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  enum status: {
    'pending' => :pending,
    'active' => :active,
    'inactive' => :inactive
  }
  # ...
end
```

Postgres will enforce that the values are valid for the type:

```
irb(main):022:0> Project.create!(status: 'foo')
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  Project Create (3.6ms)  INSERT INTO "projects" ("created_at", "updated_at", "status") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", "2020-01-16 14:15:47.579769"], ["updated_at", "2020-01-16 14:15:47.579769"], ["status", "foo"]]
   (0.4ms)  ROLLBACK
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):22
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR:  invalid input value for enum project_status: "foo")
```

The biggest con is that you need to use a SQL schema instead of a ruby schema as it cannot dump the table. But thats true for a lot of Postgres features.

Comment: I like enums in application code. But I hate them in database code. They're non-relational. They're widely unsupported, and where they *are* supported, support is inconsistent. You can't operate on them with the normal insert and delete statements. (PostgreSQL doesn't support deleting a "row" from an enum at all.)

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' those are all really valid concerns and you definitely made me reconsider. Postgres actually doesn't support deleting a value from an Enum type as it doesn't have a mechanism to deal with records that could have that value and thus become invalid. There is a workaround by declaring a new enum type and adding a new column but yeah its messy.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, the database constraint you're looking for is either a check constraint or a foreign key constraint.

For a check constraint, you'd run SQL something like this.

```
alter table your_table
  add constraint constraint_name
  check (status in ('pending', 'active', 'inactive');
```

For a foreign key constraint, you'd first build a table of valid statuses.

```
create table statuses (
  status varchar(15) primary key
);
insert into statuses values 
('pending'), ('active'), ('inactive');
```

And in the referencing table . . .

```
create table your_table (
  other_columns char(1) primary key,  
  status varchar(15) not null
    references statuses (status)
);
```

The check constraint is more resistant to changes (you have to change the database schema to add or remove valid statuses); the foreign key is easier to change (just add or delete a row), but is more open to "tampering". Regardless of which one you use, relatively few people should have sufficient privileges to change those constraints. Really few.

But, IMHO, Rails omits a much more problematic database constraint that you probably need to think about.

> This helper validates that the attribute's value is unique right before the object gets saved. It does not create a uniqueness constraint in the database . . . (From [Uniqueness helper documentation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness))

Comment: Using a foreign key is a good alternative if the list of statuses is not a developer concern and needs to be amendable by a GUI.  `primary key` will enforce uniqueness on `statuses.status` so I'm not sure what the issue is there.